# Dependencies not being released with controllers in Castle Windsor?

Tags: dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I have a dependency (say `IServiceRetriever`) that my controller calls that in turn calls another dependency. I can verify my controller is released during my "`_container.Release(controller)`" call, but my dependencies are not being released. I know this because if I call the controller again, the public property off this dependency keeps getting having items added to it (the list is created in the constructor so if a new instance is created it'd be a new list).

I have my controllers registered as LifetimeTransient, and I have no lifestyle associated with my dependency:

```
container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn<IController>().LifestyleTransient());

container.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyContaining<IServiceRetriever>()
                .Where(x => x.IsPublic)
                .WithServiceDefaultInterfaces()); //dependency that calls IQueryBuilder

container.Register(Component.For<IQueryBuilder>().ImplementedBy<QueryBuilder>()); // not being released
```

I have never seen this before, I was under the assumption that if I released the controller, Windsor would walk the dependency graph and dispose everything it finds, this is not the case. What I am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

> I have never seen this before, I was under the assumption that if I
>   released the controller, Windsor would walk the dependency graph and
>   dispose everything it finds, this is not the case.

This assumption is wrong if your dependencies use singleton life cycle. Default life cycle in Castle Windsor is singleton, you have registered IServiceRetriever and IQueryBuilder with default life cycle. Singleton objects are not released until you dispose the container. If you were to release it when no objects hold a reference to it, you may have to create another one later and it wouldn't be a singleton anymore.

Comment: Yup, it's a singleton so it doesn't get released (which is correct behaviour)